# Should translateZ be present in CSS animation keyframes rules?

Tags: css, optimization, css-animations, transform

Having some animation of `transform: scale` property, would it be enough to set `transform: translateZ(0)` only in static CSS to trigger GPU acceleration?

```
div {
    animation: scale 1s;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes scale {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Or should `transform: scale(...) translateZ(0);` be present in each @keyframe rule?

Comment: yes, otherwise transform is reset without the translatez() property . but the value set to zero, missing it won't be noticed

Comment: or use `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale3d` instead of the normal scale but pay attention to the values